# ¿Regexp bootstrapValidator?

Tags: javascript

Quién me pueda ayudar con esta expresión regular en boostrap validator.

Lo que quiero lograr es que en el input no se envié ningún 0.
Ej: 00000
Ej: 00
Ej:0

Pero que si puedan enviar 0 si están acompañados con otros dijitos.

Ej: 081809

Ej: 100200

/^[0-9][1-9]+$/

Con la expresión de arriba no me deja ingresar nigún dato si contiene algún cero.

Agradezco sus repuestas gracias.

```
$('Formulario').bootstrapValidator({

   live: 'enabled',

   fields:{

       Nameinput:{
          Validators:{
            StringLength:{
              min: 1,
              max: 2,
              message: 'LONGITUD MAXIMA DE 2'
            },
            regexp: {
              regexp: /^[0-9][1-9]+$/
              message: 'solo se permite números 
             <br> no se permiten sólo ceros'
            }

        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la RegExp

```
regexp : /^\d*[1-9]+\d*$/

regexp : /^[0-9]*[1-9]+[0-9]*$/

regexp : /^(((([0]?[1-9])|(([1-9][0-9])))))$/
```

La última valida números entre 1 y 99 ( Los parentesis es por el uso de agrupadores o matches dentro de rubular para facilitar la abstracción.

https://rubular.com/r/3A7023xarjT9h8

Explicación:

Debe iniciar ( o no) con una secuencia de numeros.

```
^[\d]*
```

Contener al menos un dígito diferente de 0.

```
[123456789]
```

y Podría terminar (o no) en otro listado de números.

```
[0-9]*$
```

https://rubular.com/r/Afei0diSy2Oy5f

Con la RegExp original no se admiten las palabras:

```
1
2
001
01
10
100
2000
```

Porque no terminan en 0

El truco es que haya al menos un dígito no 0 en medio los dos sub-grupos.